# How can I access a span inside a div to remove styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

Given this span:

```
<div class="message" data-dojo-attach-point="messageContainer">
    <span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">Foo Bar</span>
</div>
```

How can I access the inner span to remove the styling with javascript?
I've tried

```
this.messageContainer.getElementsByTagName("span").removeAttribute("style");

this.meesageContainer.removeAttribute("style");

this.messageContainer.innerHTML.removeAttribute("style");
```

The first and third return a null value so I can't use them and the second affects the div, not the span.  How can I do this?

Comment: there is `el.querySelector('span').removeAttribute` also in my lovely vanillaJS

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is close, but `.getElementsByTagName` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), so you simply need to access the first element.

```
this.messageContainer.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

Comment: [Element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), not an Array.